# HTTPS POSTS sometimes not getting to apache

Tags: macos, network, apache

On OS X 10.8.5, I have apache fronting a web app that communicates with Authorize.net. After Authorize.net completes a transaction it posts back to my app with confirmation information.

97% of the time this works fine. The 3% that doesn't work is a problem because a customer has paid for a transaction that my app doesn't know has completed.

The failed posts don't show up in apache logs. I've checked access, error and ssl_request log.

They do show up in the appfirewall.log, without anything looking any different about the successful posts vs the unsuccessful:

In this sample, the post at May 23 08:40:26 failed, the rest worked fine.

```
May 23 02:36:27 my-host.local socketfilterfw[111] <Info>: Allow httpd connecting from 12.12.123.123:2381 to port 443 proto=6
May 23 08:40:26 my-host.local socketfilterfw[111] <Info>: Allow httpd connecting from 12.12.123.123:3706 to port 443 proto=6
May 23 10:51:13 my-host.local socketfilterfw[111] <Info>: Allow httpd connecting from 12.12.123.123:1254 to port 443 proto=6
```

I'm looking for some help on where else I can look to see why apache isn't seeing these requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This article walks through a series of approaches for debugging Apache `httpd`, [Debugging Apache Web Server Problems](http://prefetch.net/articles/debuggingapache.html):

> ### Debugging requests and responses
>
> When supporting web applications, there are times when a problem can
>   be caused by an application server, proxy server or the web server
>   itself. To troubleshoot these types of issues, it is useful to dump
>   the HTTP requests and responses to isolate the problem to the local
>   system, or a remote system. The apache web server module mod_dumpio
>   can be used for this purpose, since it allows HTTP requests and/or
>   HTTP responses to be written to the error_log.

Alternatively, is your `httpd` instance occasionally saturated with requests and dropping new connections?

The techniques in the link above should help you isolate which part is encountering problems.

Failing that, try the [Webmasters StackExchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache); you may find more experienced people there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm pretty sure the request just isn't getting to Apache as none of the logs reflect it, but I can try capturing the requests. And the site isn't busy enough to be flooded.